# why I can't call map member's method directly like this

Tags: go

```
type mod struct {
    src string
    dst string
}

func(m *mod)New(){
    m.src = "a"
    m.dst = "b"
}

var(

    v = map[string]interface{} {
        "file":mod{},
        "time":mod{},
    }

)
v["file"].New()
```

I get an error:
invalid qualified type, expecting packagename.identifier, found: v["file"].New <*ast.SelectorExpr>

**Is there a way to call the member's method directly **

Comment: You mad a map of string to interface{}. Why interface? You have a perfectly good type to use.

Answer (score 3):

The value of the map is `interface{}`. It has no methods.

Instead, declare the map as:

```
v=map[string]mod {
  "file": mod{},
  "time": mod{},
}
```

Or use type assertion:

```
v["file"].(mod).New()
```

Answer (score -1):

use type assertion  works, as below:

```
a,_ := v["file"].(mod)
a.New()
```

Comment: Why use the two-return map access form if you're going to discard the second value?

Comment: @Adrian: interesting tidbit, that is actually the `ok` from the type assertion. You can use this pattern where you don't know if the key exists, but you know it will be a certain type if it does and you want the zero value. (not that we should be encouraging this obscure case for the question at hand)